# Fastest, cleanest way in linq to exclude elements from other type (+ef)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-objects

Assume we have these two classes:

```
class GenericFoo
{
   public Guid ID;
   ...
}

class SpecialFoo
{
   public Guid ID;
   public Guid GenericFooID;
   ...
}
```

GenericFoo is a kind of template class, that SpecialFoos can be created from.

Now, I have a `DbSet<GenericFoo> g` and a `DbSet<SpecialFoo> s`.
Any SpecialFoo.GenericFooID *may* exist in g, but may also be missing. (The GenericFoo may e.g. have been deleted). The opposite is true as well, of course.

What I would like is a call to get the ones that lacks matching GenericFooID, something like:

```
missing = s.Except(g)
```

That doesn't work, since Except only works for same classes. For now I've solved this by using a rather contrived solution:

```
ExistingIds = g.Select(f=>f.ID);
missing = s.Where(f => !ExistingIds.Contains(s.GenericFooID));
```

One major downside here is that we lose type safety (if someone mistype g and specifies a similar class, there would be no way to check this).
I would prefer having something like an `IComparer<type1, type2>` so that the `Except` call would work.

The other options I've found is

- to make a "fake left join" using group join, and just keeping the non matching
- to convert the first one into a dictionary, hash table etc. just to speed it up
- attempting to create a Generic->Special converter, and then a IComparer just for the sake of using `Except`

My questions are:

1. Are there any nicer way to solve this, just talking about linq to objects?
2. What is the fastest way to solve this, in the context of entity framework?

Comment: So what, is it LINQ2Objects or EF?

Comment: Well, does it make that much of a difference? L2O for question 1, EF for question 2.

Comment: Then why do you have a DBSet? Also, L2O opens up stuff like MoreLINQ.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I think I edited my reply before you got a chance to see it. Now if we can make this pretty and fast using just L2O, then I could of course just fetch everything and do it locally; highly unlikely, naturally. I would like the nicest looking solution in any situation, and the fastest solution for my specific case.

Comment: Shouldn't specialFoo inherit from genericFoo?

Comment: Nope. No such relationship in this case (of this I am certain).

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is a long shot because it's quite esoteric, but you want an outer join filtered by those without actual relationship. You could try:

```
from specialFoo in context.SpecialFoos
join genericFoo in context.GenericFoos 
     on specialFoo.GenericFooID equals genericFoo.ID 
     into gj
where !gj.Any()
select specialFoo;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the first of my "other suggestions", but expressed much more clearly. Still not a very clean solution, imo.

Answer (score -1):

This may work well for both cases:

```
var missing = s.Where(a => !g.Any(b => b.ID == a.GenericFooID));
```

Comment: Where + !Any isn't very efficient.

Comment: It would produce an `Exists` statement in SQL. Since we're dealing with keys, it should be fine.

Comment: The problem is, due to the OP's bad tagging, we don't know if it's L2O or EF.

Comment: The question ends by asking about LinqtoObjects and EF.

Comment: Now, that **looks** inefficient, but I've come to not trust my insticts when it comes to EF. One thing though: `a.GenericFooID` is not a key, neither primary or foreign. Would that make any difference?

Comment: `Exists` statements are a pretty commonly used operator and that's what the provider would output here. Try `missing.ToString()` to capture the produced sql. Then run it in SSMS with a returned execution plan. It might recommend an additional index but maybe not. And then you'll have something to measure.

Comment: Just realized another thing (one of the main points), were still out of luck on the type safety. I would like to be very specific about the comparison of GenericFoo vs SpecialFoo, since I also have another set of classes GenericBar vs SpecialBar.

Comment: I'm not sure on your meaning of type safety. The compiler enforces type safety here as normal. And your comparison can be as specific as you'd like in the `Where` function. If you mean something more to do with relational enforcement. I recommend navigation properties and proper foreign keys.

Comment: What I mean is that the comparison is on Guids instead of my classes; I'd like to be able to force this to work with just GenericFoo/SpecialFoo. I could easily make a mistake by just using a DbSet<GenericBar> instead of GenericFoo.